# Read 8 byte from specific position

Tags: php

```
$filename = '301.tdr';

$packetStream = array(
    'buffer'    => '',
    'position'  => '',
    'size'      => ''
);

$packetStream['buffer'] = fopen($filename, 'rb');
$packetStream['position'] = 0;
$packetStream['size'] = filesize($filename);

while($packetStream['position'] < $packetStream['size']) {
    $groupID = decodeInt64($packetStream['buffer'], $packetStream['position']);
    echo $groupID;
    break;
}

function decodeInt64($stream, $position) {
    fseek($stream, $position);
    $packetStream['position'] += 8;
    return bindec(fgets($stream, 8));
}
```

Hello,

I want to read 8 byte in a specific position of file. But also i want to binary read and get output as a binary. Because, this file not a string or etc. It is a binary file.

This code does not work for me, it returns 0. But i expected 5317..

Comment: Its `break`-ing on first iteration.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i know, i just want to see first 8 byte of file. And it should return 5317 but returns 0. I dont know other bytes results.. So i break after get first result

Comment: Have you tried with `fread` instead of `fgets`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca if i read 4096 byte using `fread`, it returns String unknown characters. I think the problem is here, i want to see binary 1 and 0.

Comment: Well, unless the file contains actual 0s and 1s, `bindec` wouldn't work, as it expets a string like literal `"110011000011"` or stuff like that. Is that the content of your file?

Comment: Note that `$packetStream` is undefined in your `decodeInt64()` function.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca my file contains string and unknown ascii chars. I must decode this file but i have to see string as a binary. How can i get output as a binary and convert to decimal ? Syscall, yes thank you, i will send address of buffer and remove position, after solve this problem.

Comment: you have to cycle through the bytes you read (as they are, *don't touch them*, that is remove `bindec`) and print (or whatever) their value with `ord`, one at a time

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thank you, you can write as an answer, if you want.

Comment: @Nevermore done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that you need to declare `$packetStream` as `global` at the beginning of the `decodeInt64` function, if your file contains bytes and you want to show their numerical value, you need to read them with `fread` and then get their `ord`. I'll return an array in this example.

```
function decodeInt64($stream, $position) {
    global $packetStream;
    fseek($stream, $position);
    $packetStream['position'] += 8;

    $bytes = fread($stream, 8);
    $toReturn = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $toReturn[] = ord($bytes[$i]);
    }
    return $toReturn;
}
```